# black images after uploading with use of resize-image-class

Tags: php, wordpress, class, image-processing

I am using [how-to-resize-an-image-with-php](http://buildmyweb.org/blog/how-to-resize-an-image-with-php/) as a class. Here the class:

```
class resize
{
private $image;
private $width;
private $height;
private $imageResized;

function __construct($file)
{
    // *** Open up the file
    $this->image = $this->openImage($file);
// **$file = empty!?**
    // *** Get width and height
    $this->width  = imagesx($this->image);
    $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
}

private function openImage($file)
{
    // *** Get extension
    $extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

    switch($extension)
    {
        case '.jpg':
        case '.jpeg':
            $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            break;
        case '.gif':
            $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
            break;
        case '.png':
            $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
            break;
        default:
            $img = false;
            break;
    }
    return $img;
}

public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto")
{    
    // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
    $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, strtolower($option));

    $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
    $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];

    // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
    $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight,
    $this->width, $this->height);

    // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
    if ($option == 'crop') {
        $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
    }
}

private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option)
{

   switch ($option)
    {
        case 'exact':
            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
            $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
            break;
        case 'portrait':
            $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
            $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
            break;
        case 'landscape':
            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
            $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
            break;
        case 'auto':
            $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
            $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
            break;
        case 'crop':
            $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
            $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
            break;
    }
    return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
}

private function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight)
{
    $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;
    $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;
    return $newWidth;
}

private function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth)
{
    $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;
    $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;
    return $newHeight;
}

private function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight)
{
    if ($this->height < $this->width)
    // *** Image to be resized is wider (landscape)
    {
        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
        $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
    }
    elseif ($this->height > $this->width)
    // *** Image to be resized is taller (portrait)
    {
        $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
    }
    else
    // *** Image to be resizerd is a square
    {
        if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {
            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
            $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
        } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {
            $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
            $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
        } else {
            // *** Sqaure being resized to a square
            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
            $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
        }
    }

    return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
}

private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight)
{

    $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
    $widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;

    if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
        $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
    } else {
        $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
    }

    $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
    $optimalWidth  = $this->width  / $optimalRatio;

    return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
}

private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)
{
    // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop
    $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
    $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight/ 2) - ( $newHeight/2 );

    $crop = $this->imageResized;
    //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);

    // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size
    $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth,
    $newHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
}

public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="80")
{
    // *** Get extension
    $extension = strrchr($savePath, '.');
    $extension = strtolower($extension);

    switch($extension)
    {
        case '.jpg':
        case '.jpeg':
            if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
            }
            break;

        case '.gif':
            if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
            }
            break;

        case '.png':
            // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
            $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

            // *** Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9
            $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

            if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
            }
            break;

        // ... etc

        default:
            // *** No extension - No save.
            break;
    }

    imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
}
}
```

and start it with this php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['pk'])  ) {        
    $filename = '';
    if(isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] && $_FILES['image']['error'] == 0) {
        $upldir =  wp_upload_dir();
        $upload_dir =  $upldir['basedir'].'/agent_company_logos/' ; // '/wp-content/uploads/agent_company_logos/'; 
        $filename = $_POST['pk'].'-'.$_FILES['image']['name'];  

        require_once('class/resize-image-class.php');
        $resize = new resize($filename);
        $resize->resizeImage(380, 160, 'exact');
        $resize->saveImage($upload_dir.$filename, "100");
```

It save the image file to the folder + correct resize it. But the **whole image is black**.

GD Support = enabled , GetText Support = enabled , Hash support = enabled

What is wrong with my code - with the class?

Comment: Check your error logs and also make sure that GD library is installed on your server.

Comment: I get this in debug.log: [04-May-2018 08:17:28 UTC] PHP Warning:  imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/deb96951n3/domains/domain.com/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/agent-plugin/class/resize-image-class.php on line 29

Comment: Do not know how to solve it.

Comment: You are either passing a wrong parameter OR the parameter you are passing has not been correctly initialised to whatever it should be. But as I cannot see any call to a fucntion called `imagesx()` in this code its difficult to be precise. My guess would be you need to pass the FULL PATH to the image into `$resize = new resize($filename);` rather than just the filename

Comment: The $filename is an uploaded file that will be saved as last option with  $resize->saveImage() see above code. Full path has no function in this case.